# Включение проверки атрибутов вариативного товара при добавлении в корзину на странице товара

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть вариативный товар с атрибутами: 
Размер (Маленький | Средний | Большой), 
Цвет (Черный | Красный | Белый).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы запретить добавлять вариацию товара в корзину, если в настройках товара атрибуты вариации не указаны явно. К примеру, если в настройках товара создать три вариации (см. скриншот), указав для первого ряда вариаций конкретные значения (Маленький, Средний, Большой), а во втором ряду оставить одну из вариаций "с любым значением". 
Так вот, при добавлении такой вариации ("с любым значением") в корзину, хотелось бы получать ошибку о том, что атрибут не заполнены. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: По умолчанию всё так и есть - невозможно добавить в корзину не выбрав все атрибуты

Comment: Прошу прощения, видимо я не совсем правильно изложил свою цель. Исправил вопрос.

Comment: Ещё раз-  по умолчанию невозможно добавить товар в корзину, если не будут выбраны ВСЕ атрибуты. Если ты поломал этот механизм - ищи виновного.